# Selecting features on GeoNB layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have installed QGIS 3, I have uploaded layers from Service New brunswick (GEONB), they all work fine, I am specifically trying to select a land parcel within the "parcels" layer. I have selected the layer in the list and the "select features" buttons and "start editing" buttons are greyed out.

Any ideas how to make the editing or selecting tools work?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

All layers seem to be from WMS. WMS layers cannot be edited because they are not vector layers. If the data provider also offers a WFS, you could add WFS layers to be able to select features. For editing you'd need a WFS-T and editing rights or, alternatively, you'd have to store the features from WFS locally (right-click layer | Save as ...) and then start editing.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I cannot seem to locate any WFS layer from the data provider. How do I go about storing from WFS locally?